# How to calculate compilation time of Java based tool in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In my current project, I am trying to **calculate compilation time** of **Java based tool** in eclipse. One way to calculate compile time is to use following method.

```
long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
//some tasks
long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime;
System.out.println("Elapsed milliseconds: " + difference);
```

I also tried **Metric-Eclipse plugin** but it won't give compile time. I want to calculate compilation time using some **eclipse plugin tool or other tool**. Is there any eclipse plugin/tool available to calculate compile time??

Comment: Have you tried initiating a build with bash/shell script and using bash/shell functions to time it? Would that suit your needs?

Comment: @dberm22- I tried to compile entire Java based tool using command line but it won't compile because of dependency problem. I need to compile tool using eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do this with ant.

a new java project in your workspace (say name is ws-builder)

```
ws-builder
    src
        task.ant.BuilderWorkSpaceTask.java
    build.xml
```

.classpath of project: (my eclipse version is Mars, these three jar versions may differ in older versions but it is ok)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.9.4.v201504302020/lib/ant.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources_3.10.1.v20150725-1910.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

task.ant.BuilderWorkSpaceTask class:

```
package task.ant;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IncrementalProjectBuilder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;

public class BuildWorkspaceTask extends Task implements IProgressMonitor {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws BuildException {

        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

        try {

            // IncrementalProjectBuilder.FULL_BUILD- indicates a full build.
            // IncrementalProjectBuilder.INCREMENTAL_BUILD- indicates a incremental build.
            // IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD-

            workspace.build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD, this);

        } catch (CoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void worked(int arg0) {
        log("worked(" + arg0 + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void subTask(String arg0) {
        log("subTask(" + arg0 + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void setTaskName(String arg0) {
        log("setTaskName(" + arg0 + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void setCanceled(boolean arg0) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isCanceled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void internalWorked(double arg0) {
        log("internalWorked(" + arg0 + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        log("done()");
    }

    @Override
    public void beginTask(String arg0, int arg1) {
        log("beginTask(" + arg0 + ", " + arg1 + ")");
    }

}
```

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build-workspace" name="Test">

    <path id="task-classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="workspaceBuild" classname="task.ant.BuildWorkspaceTask" classpathref="task-classpath" />

    <target name="build-workspace">
        <workspaceBuild />
    </target>

</project>
```

`Right click on build.xml > Run as > 2 Ant Build > (select) JRE (tab) > (select) Run in the same JRE as the workspace > Run`
that's it. you will see duration when ant finishes.

Comment: Thanx for the pointer. But I am not able to locate org.apache.ant_1.9.4.v201504302020/lib/ant.jar, 
org.eclipse.core.resources_3.10.1.v201507251910.jar,org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709.jar
and org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8.

Comment: you can find those three jars under eclipse(installed dir)/plugins (versions may differ but not important if different), the forth one is jre itself.

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked a way to time compile time using the Eclipse IDE, comments indicate you would be willing to accept a headless build solution, provided it works. Although you mentioned you tried this with no success, due to dependency errors, dependency errors should not stop you from building provided the project is set up correctly.

I wrote this script to use Eclipse's built-in compiler. I used it with C++ code, but should still work with Java. Assumes you are using linux. I have not tested the timing aspect of it, but you can always strip that part out and call it with [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29)

Save it as `headlessBuild.sh`, and call it with either `sh headlessBuild.sh -c` or `sh headlessBuild.sh -r`. You can also call it with `time headlessBuild.sh` to use linux's built-in command timer.

```
#!/bin/sh

args=`getopt hrcs: $*`
set -- $args

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo ""
  echo "Usage: headlessBuild {args}"
  echo ""
  echo "-c        cleans and rebuilds workspace"
  echo "-r        rebuilds workspace without cleaning (default)"
  echo ""
  exit 1
fi

currDir=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
WORKSPACE_ROOT=/home/user/workspace
nbr=0

PROJ_NAME[$nbr]='ProjectName1'
PROJ_EXE[$nbr]='ProjectName1/Debug'
TARGET[$nbr]='TargetName1.so'
nbr=$(( nbr+1 ))

PROJ_NAME[$nbr]='ProjectName2'
PROJ_EXE[$nbr]='ProjectName2/Debug'
TARGET[$nbr]='TargetName2.so'
nbr=$(( nbr+1 ))



buildType="build"
for i; do
  case "$i" in
    -c  ) buildType="cleanBuild"
          shift;
          ;;
    -r  ) buildType="build"
          shift;
          ;;
    --  ) shift; 
          break;
          ;;
  esac
done


echo ' '
echo 'BUILDING PROJECTS...'
echo ' '
STARTTIME=$(date +%s)

nbr=0
for proj in "${PROJ_NAME[@]}" ; do

    if [ "$buildType" = "cleanBuild" ]; then

        ####### ensure rebuild by deleting current target, if it exists
        name=$WORKSPACE_ROOT'/'"${PROJ_EXE[$nbr]}"'/'"${TARGET[$nbr]}"
        if [[ -f $name ]]; then
            echo '   Removing exising executable:' $name
            rm $name
        fi;
    fi;

    echo '   Building ' $proj
    eclipse -nosplash -data $WORKSPACE_ROOT --launcher.suppressErrors -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild  -import $WORKSPACE_ROOT'/'$proj -$buildType "${PROJ_EXE[$nbr]}" > "${LOGFILENAME[$nbr]}" -vmargs -Declipse.exitdata=""
done 

ENDTIME=$(date +%s)
echo ' '
echo "Elapsed Time: $(($ENDTIME - $STARTTIME)) s"
```

Comment: @dberm22- Thanx for the pointer. But I don't have background to understand your answer. Could you please suggest some tool ?? It would be grateful for me.

Comment: First, are you on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: @dberm- I am using Windows.

Comment: This script is for linux based builds, but I'm sure the calls/script would be similar for Windows.

Comment: @dberm22- Thanx for the effort.